# Переопределение параметра по умолчанию

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Возникла ошибка с переопределением, не могу понять почему.

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H    

class String
{
public:
    String(const char *str="");
    ~String();

    int  Len() const {return n;}
    void Print() const ;
private:

    char *s;
    int n;

};

#endif
```

2 файл:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

String ::String(const char *str="")
{

    n = strlen(str);
    s = new char[n+1];
    //здесь д.б. обработка ошибка

    strcpy(s,str);

}

String :: ~String()
{
    delete[] s;

}

void String :: Print() const 
{
    cout<<s;

}
```

3 файл:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    String a("Hello, world!");

    cout << "String a: \"";
    a.Print();
    cout << "\", Len = " << a.Len() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Ошибка отладчика VS 2010:

> `1>------ Построение начато: проект: String, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------ 1>Построение начато 28.01.2012 18:26:23. 1>InitializeBuildStatus: 1>  Обращение к "Debug\String.unsuccessfulbuild". 1>ClCompile: 1>  useString.cpp 1>  String.cpp 1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\string\string\string.cpp(7): error C2572: String::String: переопределение параметра по умолчанию: параметр 1 1>          c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\string\string\string.h(8): см. объявление "String::String" 1>  Создание кода... 1> 1>СБОЙ построения.`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему она произошла?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя переопределять параметры по умолчанию. Во одном из файлов вместо:

```
String(const char *str="")
```

Должно быть:

```
String(const char *str)
```

Comment: Ага, или String(){n=0; s=0;}

Answer (score 0):

Только что столкнулся с такой же проблемой)) Все дело в том, что значения по умолчанию, должны быть указаны только при объявлении, уберите значения по умолчанию из определения и ошибка уйдет. 
class String
{
public:
    String(const char *str=""); Здесь оставить

String ::String(const char *str="") тут заменить на

String ::String(const char *str)